# How can I access BIOS if I've installed Windows 8 in Legacy Boot Mode (not UEFI)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, bios

I've installed Windows 8 on a laptop meant for Windows 7. So it lacks the UEFI firmware which Windows 8 uses. My aim is to boot from a bootable USB. I can't get into BIOS/access boot preferences by the usual F2/F12 method. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Windows 8 fully supports BIOS you should be able to access your UEFI BIOS without issue

Comment: Read your motherboard or system manual to know how to access the BIOS. Win8 will have no problems with it.